# How change the syntax in Elasticsearch 8 where 'body' parameter is deprecated?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

After updating Python package elasticsearch from 7.6.0 to 8.1.0, I started to receive an error at this line of code:

```
count = es.count(index=my_index, body={'query': query['query']} )["count"]
```

receive following error message:

> DeprecationWarning: The 'body' parameter is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instead use individual parameters.
> count = es.count(index=ums_index, body={'query': query['query']}
> )["count"]

I don't understand how to use the above-mentioned "*individual parameters*".
Here is my query:

```
query = {
    "bool": {
        "must": 
        [
                {"exists" : { "field" : 'device'}},
                {"exists" : { "field" : 'app_version'}},                    
                {"exists" : { "field" : 'updatecheck'}},
                {"exists" : { "field" : 'updatecheck_status'}},
                {"term" : { "updatecheck_status" : 'ok'}},
                {"term" : { "updatecheck" : 1}},
                {
                    "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": from_date,
                        "lte": to_date,
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd"
                        }
                    }
                }
        ],
        "must_not":
        [
                {"term" : { "device" : ""}},
                {"term" : { "updatecheck" : ""}},
                {"term" : { "updatecheck_status" : ""}},
                {
                    "terms" : { 
                        "app_version" : ['2.2.1.1', '2.2.1.2', '2.2.1.3', '2.2.1.4', '2.2.1.5',
                                        '2.2.1.6', '2.2.1.7', '2.1.2.9', '2.1.3.2', '0.0.0.0', '']
                    }
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

In the official documentation, I can't find any chance to find examples of how to pass my query in new versions of Elasticsearch.

Possibly someone has a solution for this case other than reverting to previous versions of Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the documentation, this is now to be done as follows:

```
# ✅ New usage:
es.search(query={...})

# ❌ Deprecated usage:
es.search(body={"query": {...}})
```

So the queries are done directly in the same line of code without "body", substituting the api you need to use, in your case "count" for "search".
You can try the following:

```
# ✅ New usage:
es.count(query={...})

# ❌ Deprecated usage:
es.count(body={"query": {...}})
enter code here
```

You can find out more by clicking on the following link:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1698

For example, if the query would be:

```
GET index-00001/_count
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {
        }
    }
}
```

Python client would be the next:

```
my_index = "index-00001"
query =  {
           "match_all": {
            }
          }
hits = en.count(index=my_index, query=query)
```

or

```
hits = en.count(index=my_index, query={"match_all": {}})
```

Comment: When I try to modify the parameter as recommended: """count = en.count(index= my_index, query=query['query'] )["count"]""" instead of """count = en.count(index= my_index, body={'query': query['query']} )["count"]""" - I receive this error "The client noticed that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not support this unknown product"

Comment: I've updated the answer with a example. I hope that It works or is useful

Comment: I think the error message communicates that there are connection problems with your elasticsearch cluster, not with the query
You could try this: client = Elasticsearch(cloud_id=CLOUD_ID,basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD)) and then : client.info(). https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/master/connecting.html

Comment: Hello, I am using the following code and is not working, what i am doing wrong? app_search.search(
        engine_name = my_engine,
        query = {"myidenti" : number}
    )     and It is giving me an error of 400 how it comes?

Comment: You should know more details to be able to identify the reason for error 400.
With the information you have provided me, I can only ask you if you have tried to change the parameter "engine_name", for another one that is available such as "index":

app_search.search( index = my_engine, query = {"myidenti" : number} )

Answer (score 8):

Using Elasticsearch 8.4.1, I got the same warning when creating indices via Python client.

I had to this this way instead:

```py
settings = {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
}
mappings = {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "numeric_detection": "true",
    "_source": {
      "enabled": "true"
    },
    "properties": {
      "p_text": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "p_vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 768
      },
    }
  }

es.indices.create(index=index_name, settings=settings, mappings=mappings)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it worked for client 8.10.1 as well